# Drop down list showing whole DataTable instead of the specified column?

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu, datatable, infragistics

someForm.designer.cs

```
private Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraCombo cmb;
cmb.DisplayMember = "valueColumn";
cmb.ValueMember = "IDColumn";
```

someForm.cs

```
SomeDS.SomeDTDataTable temp = new SomeDS.SomeDTDataTable();
this.cmb.DataSource = temp;
this.cmb.DataBind();

this.dataGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["someColumn"].EditorControl = this.cmb;
```

`SomeDS.SomeDTDataTable` have multiple columns and now for each `cmb`, instead of showing only `valueColumn`, it shows all the columns? May I know which part could've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. UltraCombo creates Layout matching the one of the DataTable you assigned as DataSource. To hide all the columns but the valueColumn you can handle InitializeLayout of the combo and set Hidden to all other columns to true like this:

```
this.cmb.InitializeLayout += Cmb_InitializeLayout;

private void Cmb_InitializeLayout(object sender, InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var col in e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns)
    {
        if(col.Header.Caption != "valueColumn")
        {
            col.Hidden = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public void AssignDropDown(DataTable dt)
    {
        //To Show Only DisplayMember in UltraCombo

```
    string[] fields = new string[]{ dt.Columns[0].ToString() };

    ugReqLine.DisplayMember = dt.Columns[0].ToString();
    ugReqLine.DataSource = dt;
    ugReqLine.ValueMember = dt.Columns[1].ToString();

    ugReqLine.SetColumnFilter(fields);   
}
```

Comment: Please, edit your answer, format your code (the `{}` button) and explain a bit how your solution helps.